# How to join two entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

Im new to Entity Framework and This is my code i have written for one entity to join.

```
BioStarEntities BS = new BioStarEntities();
TB_USER tuser = BS.TB_USER.SingleOrDefault(p => p.sUserID=="11");
foreach (var tTemplates in tuser.TB_USER_TEMPLATE)
{
    byte[] tempp2 = tTemplates.bTemplate;
}
```

Here instead of UserId == 11 i want to get all user entities, so what do i have to use instead of keyword SingleOrDefualt?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a database relation in between table `TB_Users` and `TB_USER_Template` and what approach you are following Code First or do you have an `edmx` ?

Comment: what is biostarentities? its type?

Comment: @Raj, it looks like `DbContext`

Comment: BioStarEntities is the .edmx 
TB_Users and TB_USER_Template are the Entites
"nUserIdn" is the attribute which join two entites (its the primary key of TB_USER)

Comment: thanks habib and keizer. I will check it and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  BioStarEntities BS = new BioStarEntities();
        var tuserS = BS.TB_USERS.ToList();
```

This will work if you've checked **Pluralization**  while generating entities from database.
If you have not you can **update model from database** and mark those **Pluralize and Singularize** check boxes I advice.

Comment: Yes i have checked Pluralization, then it generates an error by saying, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BussinessLibraries.TB_USER>' to 'BussinessLibraries.TB_USER'

Do i have to change TB_USER tuser type?

Comment: It says it while calling ToList()?

Comment: var tuserS = BS.TB_USERS.ToList(); Look at this. here should write pluralized class like BS.TB_USERS.ToList(); NOT BS.TB_USER.ToList();

Comment: you need to initialize a variable List<TB_User> tb_users = BS.TB_Users.ToList();

Answer (score 1):

`BS.TB_USER.FindAll(r => r.userID = "11")` will retrieve all values. However i want to know the type of TB_User so that I can help you where you stuck.

Comment: Well i want to have all the users, not just the user whose id is "11"
TB_USER is an entity which belongs to BioStarEntities edmx

Comment: ok but there is no FindAll, there only All. Do i have to change return type TB_USER tuser into TB_USER []tuser

Comment: Yep. or otherwise you may use ToList() method if available use it. or list<TB_User> tUser = new list<TB_User>(BS.TB_User.All());

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined relationship in database as well as in `EDMX` and if its a one to many relationship between `TB_USER` and `TB_USER_TEMPLATE` then you will have a property in the `TB_USER` type object which will contain the related `TB_USER_TEMPLATES` (probably, you may have to check the name in intellisence).

```
TB_USER tuser = BS.TB_USER.SingleOrDefault(p => p.sUserID=="11");
var TemplatesForUsers = tuser.TB_USER_TEMPLATES;
```

the above will give you all the template for a particular user.

Comment: Yes i have done that, that code works perfectly with SingleOrDefualt, so now i want all users templates, how do i get all employees